# Asynchronous UserControl

Tags: c#, concurrency, windows-runtime, async-await

I’ve created my own charting library. So far everything works fine except the drawing part is not concurrent. How can I achieve that? Right now my screen is freezing while adding item to the chart control. I’ve tried to rewrite the adding function as `Task.Run(()=> { adding to the ObservableCollection })` but without success.

Is it only making all method within the library `async`? If yes, what do I return since I need at least one `Task`?

Is there another way to create an asynchronous control, I mean in general? My wish is to have a control like the `ListView` where I can add items and the new items are added concurrent to the list.

Comment: Are you using wpf or winform ?

Comment: If basic `listOfItems.Add(existingItem);Invalidate();` freezes your view no amount of asynchronous code will help... (Also your definition of "adding item to the chart" could be very different, but I'd recommend spelling it out if it is the case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI controls are thread-affine, they can only be handled from the UI thread, that is why you're seeing `Task.Run` fail.

There is a general rule that you shouldn't occupy the UI with with CPU bound work for more than 50ms. If you have a large amount of data to process with UI controls, try batching the work into smaller work groups and freeing your UI thread between iterations.

In general, you shouldn't expose [*asynchronous wrappers over sync methods*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx).

Let the user explicitly offload whichever work he has to a background thread.

Comment: Thanks, that means all is a matter of time? "If you have a large amount of data to process with UI controls, try batching the work into smaller work groups and freeing your UI thread between iterations." What does this mean? How can I freeing the UI?

Comment: @Dani - seperate the large list into sub lists and perhaps use a `await Task.Delay(50);` to let the UI "breath"